# Getting the rest of an object after a lodash pick

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a terse lodash shorthand to get the rest of an object after a pick at the same time?

Let's say I do something like this:

```js
const data = {
   name: 'Joost',
   location: 'UK',
   status: 'On Stack Overflow'
}

const bioFields = ['name', 'location'];

const bio = pick(data, bioFields);
const rest = omit(data, bioFields);
```

It would be nice to just have a succinct `const [bio, rest] = pickWithRest(data, bioFields)` oneliner.

I thought a version of [partition](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) might do this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I know there's probably a bunch of ways to do this with a few extra lines/characters of code, just wondering if I am missing something that's satisfyingly short.

Assume that the list of fields that I am using is dynamic.

Comment: @mplungjan that will still need another line to create the `{ name, loc }` object

Comment: @mplungjan This also doesn't work when my field list is dynamic (ie. they are defined as a const array elswhere and used as `bioFIelds` in multiple places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function using lodash's `_.over()` with `_.pick()` and `.omit()`:

```js
const pickWithRest = _.over([_.pick, _.omit])

const data = { name: 'Joost', location: 'UK', status: 'On Stack Overflow' }
const bioFields = ['name', 'location'];

const [bio, rest] = pickWithRest(data, bioFields)

console.log({
  bio,
  rest
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I did not know about `over`. This is neat, thanks!